How to add Selection field in odoo17 with options depending on value of other field
I need the selection field options to be dynamically updated immediately when the value of a certain field changes.
I tried it this way, but it didn't work
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    field1 = fields.Integer(store=False)
    field2 = fields.Selection(store=False, selection='comp_fl2')


    @api.onchange('field1')
    def _time_fields(self):
        self.field2 = False


    def comp_fl2(self):
        if self.field1:
            if self.field1 > 5:
                return[('one','one'),('two','two')]
            else:
                return [('three', 'three'), ('four', 'four')]
        return []

The problem is that he doesn't see the value of field 1
I tried adding an onchange decorator to it, but in that case the function should return a dictionary and not a list.
@api.onchange('field1')
    def comp_fl2(self):
        if self.field1:
            if self.field1 > 5:
                return[('one','one'),('two','two')]
            else:
                return [('three', 'three'), ('four', 'four')]
        return []

It is also not possible to convey this value through context.

it seems to me that it is not the best way to achieve what you want. Could you please explain the wider scope of your goal ?

I want to implement a doctor's appointment. Odoo does not provide the ability to show busy times in the calendar and I want to make it possible for the user to select a date in fields.Date() and depending on the date selection, another field will be prompted to select a free time.
